# Fortran, double free or corruption (!prev) (discriminator 2)

Tags: fortran

I have a little problem while running my FORTRAN code.

This error occur when I try to DEALLOCATE a specific variable.

I actually don't have a clue on how to find a way to solve my problem...

My error message are the following :

```
Error in `my_app.x': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000042e5520 **
Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.
#8  0x6F692B in __My_mod_deallocate_VARIABLE at deallocate_VARIABLE.f:415 (discriminator 2)
```

To deal with my issue, I've used all kind of GNU FORTRAN compiler options :

```
-g -Wall -fbacktrace -finit-local-zero -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow  -fbounds-check -fcheck=all
```

And I'm actually trying to print different value :

In first place when I'm allocating my variable :

```
  INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:) ::   MY_VARIABLE 
  ALLOCATE(MY_VARIABLE (257))
  MY_VARIABLE = 0

  WRITE(7,*), 'IAM ALLOCATIONG MY VARIABLE'
  IF (ALLOCATED (MY_VARIABLE)) WRITE(7,*), 'MY_VARIABLE_ALLOCATED ','OUI'
  IF (.NOT.ALLOCATED(MY_VARIABLE)) WRITE(7,*),'MY_VARIABLE ','NON'
  WRITE(7,*),'09 LOC(MY_VARIABLE   )',LOC( MY_VARIABLE    )
  WRITE(7,*), '09 SHAPE  (MY_VARIABLE)',  SHAPE(MY_VARIABLE)
  WRITE(7,*), '09 LBOUND (MY_VARIABLE)', LBOUND(MY_VARIABLE)
  WRITE(7,*), '09 UBOUND (MY_VARIABLE)', UBOUND(MY_VARIABLE)
```

And I have some satisfying result :

```
IAM ALLOCATIONG MY VARIABLE
 09 MY_VARIABLE_ALLOCATED    OUI     
 09 LOC(MY_VARIABLE   )             76719840
 09 SHAPE  (MY_VARIABLE)         257
 09 LBOUND (MY_VARIABLE)           1
 09 UBOUND (MY_VARIABLE)         257
```

Then, some routines are running, and before the end of the execution, I want to deallocate MY_VARIABLE.

Just before deallocating my variable, I performing another test :

```
  WRITE(7,*), 'IAM DEALLOCATIONG MY VARIABLE'
  IF (ALLOCATED (MY_VARIABLE)) WRITE(7,*), 'MY_VARIABLE_ALLOCATED ','OUI'
  IF (.NOT.ALLOCATED(MY_VARIABLE)) WRITE(7,*),'MY_VARIABLE ','NON'
  WRITE(7,*),'09 LOC(MY_VARIABLE   )',LOC( MY_VARIABLE    )
  WRITE(7,*), '09 SHAPE  (MY_VARIABLE)',  SHAPE(MY_VARIABLE)
  WRITE(7,*), '09 LBOUND (MY_VARIABLE)', LBOUND(MY_VARIABLE)
  WRITE(7,*), '09 UBOUND (MY_VARIABLE)', UBOUND(MY_VARIABLE)
```

And again the result are :

```
IAM DEALLOCATIONG MY VARIABLE
 09 MY_VARIABLE_ALLOCATED    OUI     
 09 LOC(MY_VARIABLE   )             76719840
 09 SHAPE  (MY_VARIABLE)         257
 09 LBOUND (MY_VARIABLE)           1
 09 UBOUND (MY_VARIABLE)         257
```

Then, I use the FORTRAN DEALLOCATING statement :

```
  DEALLOCATE( MY_VARIABLE )
```

And I sadly have my running error.

Does anyone have some clue on how to solve this kind of error ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome, this kind of error is a *heap corruption*. The error can be *anywhere*. We need the full code. See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Do you _need_ to deallocate the variable? the compiler will de-allocate automatically when the function goes out of scope.

Comment: Ok ... My code have more than 4000 lines. So ... if someone have some experiences or some idea on how to close the area where my error could be, this will be fine. 
But, maybe the best I have to do is to localize this error with "alinea DDT" as I've the lucky right to use it.

Comment: ... So, this error could be "stack over flow" ? This mean that somewhere, an array variable could write a value out of his memory boundary ?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand how this kind of error could occur.
For example, if I try the following FORTRAN code : 
 ALLOCATE(MY_VARIABLE(1:4))
 MY_VARIABLE(0) = 1
I will immediately have an Index error! 
 Are this kind of error could be due to the use of the MPI library .
Thanks again.

Comment: if the thing is allocated (1:4) then where is element (0)? In my mind it is to the left of one... you may want it to be between 1 and 4 inclusive.

Comment: The simple error you show `ALLOCATE(MY_VARIABLE(1:4)) MY_VARIABLE(0) = 1` will be caught by `-fcheck=bounds`, but more complicated ones will not be! Remember, in assumed size dummy arguments (`array(*)`) the compiler does not even know how big the array is. And if you make an error in MPI procedure calls, *anything* can happen. To ease your debugging, use `use mpi` and not `include "mpif.h"`. But how much it help and if at all depends on too many variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VladimirF

Comment: in fortran, by default the subroutines are compiled independently. There is no way for the compiler to realize that this or that subroutine uses variables "outside" their definition field.
For example:
SUBROUTINE ROUTINE_1
    INTERGER, DIMENSION (3) :: TOTO
    TOTO = (/ (1,2,3) /)
    CALL ROUTINE_2 (TOTO)
END SUBROUTINE ROUTINE_1

SUBROUTINE ROUTINE_2 (TOTO)
    REAL, DIMENSION (4) :: TOTO
    TOTO (5) = 3.14
END SUBROUTINE ROUTINE_2

will not be identified as an error by the compiler, but will lead to a memory corruption for the memory variable adjacent to TOTO.
Thank you all

Comment: Unless you use modules and assumed shape arrays. Then much more is possible.